# Dynamic Way To Transpose SQL Table Similar to Excel Functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've looked around a good amount and haven't found quite the correct solution to what I think is a very simple problem. Everything I find focuses on one value being tranposed, but here I have a bunch.

I have this table currently and I want to transpose it exactly how Excel would. What is the easiest way to do this?

What I have:

```
nodeid  | Headcount | FTE | Count of Part-Time Employees | Count of Non-Permanent Employees |
Actuals | 12        | 13  | 23                           | 35                               |
Targets | 15        | 15  | 25                           | 25                               |
```

What I want:

```
nodeid                           | Actuals | Targets |
Headcount                        | 12      | 15      |
FTE                              | 13      | 15      |
Count of Part-Time Employees     | 23      | 25      |
Count of Non-Permanent Employees | 35      | 25      |
```

Comment: You can `UNPIVOT` to get your columns as rows, and then `PIVOT` once again to put your `actuals` and `targets` into their own columns. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2016+, you can use a bit of JSON to "dynamically" unpivot your data, and then simply apply a PIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([nodeid] varchar(50),[Headcount] int,[FTE] int,[Count of Part-Time Employees] int,[Count of Non-Permanent Employees] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Actuals',12,13,23,35)
,('Targets',15,15,25,25)

Select * 
 From  (
        Select A.NodeID
              ,B.* 
          From @YourTable A
          Cross Apply (
                         Select [Node]  = [Key]
                               ,[Value] = try_convert(int,Value)
                          From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) ) B
                          Where try_convert(int,value) is not null
        ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for [NodeID] in ([Actuals],[Targets]) ) pvt
 Order By Node desc
```

**Returns**

```
Node                                Actuals Targets
Headcount                           12      15
FTE                                 13      15
Count of Part-Time Employees        23      25
Count of Non-Permanent Employees    35      25
```

**Note:**  If <2016 there is an similar XML approach.

Comment: This is very helpful. Is there a way to have the Cross Apply section accept Float or Int?

Comment: @EmmettOgiony  It would have to be one or the other.  With a PIVOT, you can't mix data types.   So if you need the precision, use FLOAT

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unpivot` and `pivot` to achieve that.

try the following:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE
(nodeid                             VARCHAR(100), 
 Headcount                          INT, 
 FTE                                INT, 
 [Count of Part-Time Employees]     INT, 
 [Count of Non-Permanent Employees] INT
);
INSERT INTO @tab SELECT 'Actuals', 12, 13, 23, 35;       
INSERT INTO @tab SELECT 'Targets', 15, 15, 25, 25;

SELECT *FROM @tab;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM
(
    SELECT nodeid, 
           Headcount, 
           FTE, 
           [Count of Part-Time Employees], 
           [Count of Non-Permanent Employees]
    FROM @tab
) t UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN(Headcount, 
                           FTE, 
                           [Count of Part-Time Employees], 
                           [Count of Non-Permanent Employees])) upvt;
DECLARE @collist VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @collist = STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(nodeid)
                            FROM #temp
                            ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME(nodeid) FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '');
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)= 'select col as nodeid, Actuals, Targets
                            from #temp t
                            pivot
                            (
                                max(val) for nodeid IN (' + @collist + ')
                            )pvt';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Please see the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a139d4fe01f549d385174a4ca17d7a2)